# How to save the uploaded file to a folder?

Tags: rust, graphql, actix-web

With this function I receive a file via graphql, How do I save the received content to a folder?

```
async fn single_upload(&self, ctx: &Context<'_>, file: Upload) -> FileInfo {
    let mut storage = ctx.data_unchecked::<FileStorage>().lock().await;
    println!("files count: {}", storage.len());
    let entry = storage.vacant_entry();
    let upload = file.value(ctx).unwrap();
    let info = FileInfo {
        id: entry.key().into(),
        filename: upload.filename.clone(),
        mimetype: upload.content_type,
    };

    entry.insert(info.clone());
    info
}
```

I am using async-graphql and actix-web